# Could "imply" be used to "explain" in one passage

Tags: comparison

I have a hard time telling what's the difference between using "implication" and "explanation" in the following passage:

> Even fatal pathogens can achieve evolutionary success. One implication is that a pathogen's virulence is a function of its mode of transmission.

Wouldn't it mean almost the same if I replace implication with explanation?

> Even fatal pathogens can achieve evolutionary success. One explanation is that a pathogen's virulence is a function of its mode of transmission.

Answer (score 2):

An implication is a meaning or significance that can be inferred from a a piece of information or multiple pieces of information. For example, Sally is a cat, and all cats have nine lives. The implication of knowing both of these things is that Sally has nine lives.

An explanation is a type of elaboration. They're used to communicate why something has happened or to provide more information and something to help the listener or reader better understand. For example, if I tell you that Jake is an opthalmologist, I might also explain that an opthalmologist is a doctor who specializes in caring your the eyes.

Implications differ from explanations in that implications can be inferred from information presented without the information actually telling you while explanations, where present, are given in the text/speech.

I hope you can see through this explanation of the difference between implication and explanation that you can't generally swap either word for the other. In the examples given, you can sort of swap them, but that's coincidental and changes the meaning of the sentence quite a bit.